# Simple eval table not displaying in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET 4.5,

I'm trying to implement a simple eval function from W.Sanders book. I can see the data in the website **but the displayed data is not in a table.**

Thank you.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>



        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td> <%# Eval("FirstName")%></td>
                    <td> <%# Eval("LastName")%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees", cnn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Repeater1.DataSource = dr;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            cnn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want Repeater1.DataSource = dr?

Comment: You're setting your data source as the connection. This will not work. You have to read the data and then bind that to the repeater.

Comment: Where is the beginning of table? No table tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the data in a table, yet you have no table in your HTML:

```
<table>
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
          <td> <%# Eval("FirstName")%></td>
          <td> <%# Eval("LastName")%></td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```